# CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIBRARIES)

Tags: cmake

I have a project .When I want to configure it in `CMAKE3.9.6` with `Visual Studio 2010` and support of Intel `Parallel Studio 2015` with this command in command line
:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10"
```

I get this error:

```
  CMake Error at     cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:615 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:113 (FIND_PACKAGE)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

All the output is as:

```
The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 15.0.2.20150121
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2015/bin/ia32/ifort.exe
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2015/bin/ia32/ifort.exe  — works
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
Determine Intel Fortran Compiler Implicit Link Path
Determine Intel Fortran Compiler Implicit Link Path — done
Checking whether C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2015/bin/ia32/ifort.exe supports Fortran 90
Checking whether C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2015/bin/ia32/ifort.exe supports Fortran 90 — yes
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe — works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe — works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:47 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:615 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:113 (FIND_PACKAGE)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/FreshElmerForCmake396/elmerfem/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Fortran Compiler and Visual Studio works but I think there is a mistake in CMAKE so it could not find some internally files or correct PATH.I download binary MSI version of CMAKE. I used cmake-gui the error was same.so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When CMake's dependency finding mechanism fails to automatically find dependency X (MPI in your case), and you know you have X available, the correct procedure is to tell CMake where to find X, or how to find it. Use either the CMake GUI or `ccmake` to set the appropriate variable(s).

In your case, the [documentation for the FindMPI module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html) indicates setting `MPI_C_COMPILER` to point to the appropriate MPI compiler wrapper could be enough for the dependency finder to catch on.

Comment: Would you give me  code lines that were suitable (as syntax and format)for solving of my first error and the second one.you answer is a little ambitious.

Comment: I copied my modules folder contents into program file /cmake and this project cmake folder.and change visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2010 win64 in cmake-gui. So this question solved.but noticed that my project configuration stopped at another error findblas.cmake. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040420/cmake-error-at-cmake-modules-findblas-cmake699-message-a-required-library-wi?noredirect=1#comment83051435_48040420